# How to stop python printing more than one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I have a small function to check if a number is prime or not. It works fine apart from one small detail - it prints out more than one `print` line on the program end.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number to find if it is prime:  "))

def is_prime():
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("Not prime")
            break
        else:
            print("The number {} is prime".format(n))

is_prime()
```

If I enter the number 2 for e.g. when the program runs, it prints:

`the number 2 is prime`

`the number 2 is prime`

`the number 2 is prime`

It only needs to print the line once, so why is this?

Comment: What happens? What doesn't happen? Please provide a clear question.

Comment: For some specific input, what is the expected *and actual* output? And please put your question in the question itself, and keep the title as a short summary of your problem. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It doesn't. It repeatedly prints "The number X is prime" until it finds that it isn't. If you only want to print when it actually *is* prime, then the else needs to go outside the loop.

Comment: So it works perfectly fine when I enter a number. However when a number is prime for e.g. I enter 7..it prints
"The number 7 is prime
The number 7 is prime
The number 7 is prime
The number 7 is prime
The number 7 is prime" 
instead of just printing once. No idea why?

Comment: And this seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TheWonderer because you iterate the loop n times, n being the number you enter. and it will print the else part every iteration

Comment: "why does it print more than one line?" - because you put it in a loop?

Comment: I suggest you put `n`, as function argument like so `is_prime(n)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `else` is in the wrong position.  You have it on the `if`, but you actually want it on the `for`.

It might not be well known, but you can have a `else` on `for`-loops and it will execute if no `break` was executed during the loops.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number to find if it is prime:  "))

def is_prime():
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("Not prime")
            break
    else:
        print("The number {} is prime".format(n))

is_prime()
```